# Adding and deleting contacts as a singular object package (like in Facebook messenger)

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, messenger

The problem I have had with this is just being able to type what I mean in few enough words to find anything meaningful in the internet.

This is what I want (sorry for the low quality image):

[image]

Search through a list of contacts, when you click on they are added as a contact package instead of a long name string. If then we click delete next to it then the whole contact is removed. This is the system used by most chat and txting services for adding contacts.

I am hoping that there will be a good github library online or, failing that, that someone can suggest the best way to proceed coding it myself.

Having thought about it somewhat I would think that I would want to treat the object a bit like I would an emoticon. Although it looks like a much longer word we would allocate a string package to the user which when detected would look up their name and output their name in the bubble. If we delete any of the string package then the whole thing becomes void and is deleted.

This is all much easier said than done of course.

So this question is trying to ask two main questions:

1. What is this actually called (this would be a great start to enable me to get more than 0 search results)
2. Is there a good github or online library that deals with this, if not then any advice on how to do it manually would be great

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through lots of different libraries which enabled this. The problem about git hub libraries is always that you have to compromise between the one which is the best and the ones which are getting updated and have recent activity.

The one which I settled with and is working out excellently can be found here and is called the [VENTokenField](https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField/blob/master/VENTokenField/VENToken.h)

If this link is broken then just search in google for VenTokenField and it is the github library by venmo.

I found it very easy to use:

Add the delegate to your header file: VENTokenFieldDelegate

Create a property in the header file too:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet VENTokenField * _tokenField;
```

I then found the easiest way to set it up was to add a UITextField to the XIB file and class it as a VenTokenField. (don't forget to set the constraints to enable the tokenField to get bigger so constrain the uitableview to the bottom of the field)

Then you just need to link in your search logic but as this is a question about the library and not the code I won't go into it here.

Hope this helps and comment if you are struggling and I'll try to update the answer to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain when should I initiate the search? Is there a delegate method that gets called whenever user types a new character? Do I get search string passed as an argument? My client wants live search, so results should update every time with new character.

Comment: Yes there is the delegate method: - (void)tokenField:(VENTokenField *)tokenField didChangeText:(NSString *)text this is where I have put my search code. I dealt with this using an array which the tableView loads from, when the user types a letter I search and refresh the array with the results, reload the data. Does this help?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have some more questions. I have noticed that default heigh of VENTokenField view is 44pt. I would like to put it in 40pt View. If I do this when I click on the TokenField it animates a little bit and I can scroll it up and down although it is empty. How can I set the default size to 40pt?  I have tried maxHeight property but it does not change anything.  Also how can I change left constraint of the To: label? I would like it to be 4 pt from the edge of the containing view. Thanks

Comment: I added the VENToken field in the XIB instead of programatically (add a textField and change its class to VENToken class), I also added it inside a UIView, this meant I could constrain the VENT to the UIView and when the VENT got bigger I could change the view to match that. I constrained my UIView to the tableView below and also set it's starting height but made that constraint have a lower priority so it could be changed.

Comment: Then I added this code in every function that had additions or removals so the height would change (didChangeText, didDeleteToken and didSelectRow): [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            _tokenView.keepHeight.equal = _tokenField.bounds.size.height;
        }];
You can see we adjust the UIView containing the VENT to the new size of the VENT (note tokenView and tokenField) which meant as tokens were added or removed the VENT gets bigger and smaller appropriately. Hope this helps